# Debug OpenCV images in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, watch

Visual Studio allows to visualize OpenCV images using Image Watch plugin (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d) during debug. This is very helpful for computer vision coding.

What is the proffered way to visualize images in Python binding to OpenCV? I am aware that it is possible to use cv2.imshow("name", image) but that is not very practical in contrast to Image Watch which allows to show many images at the same time and automatically does the update after change.

Is there any alternative to Image Watch for Python?

Answer (score 5):

If you use `VSCode`, you can try the `simply_view_image_for_python_opencv_debugging` `VSCode-Extension`.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnguo.simply-view-image-for-python-opencv-debugging

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe you'll want to look at [Visual-Logging](https://github.com/dchaplinsky/visual-logging). It can produce a rather nice collection of your output that you can just open up in a browser. It is pip installable like so:

```
pip install visual-logging
```

[Here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/22/visual-logging-new-favorite-tool-debugging-opencv-python-apps/) is a page with a concise walkthrough that shows how it is used.

It's not nearly as fancy as that Visual Studio tool, but it might be your best option that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems, so I've just created OpenCV Image Viewer Plugin, which works as you expect. You can install it to any JetBrains IDE, which support Python (directly or via plugin).

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]